# Standard overlay and styled legacy scrollbars

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

By default on a Mac when you don't have a mouse connected to your laptop you see beautiful overlay scrollbars both on Chrome and Safari which appear only while scrolling. But when a mouse is connected, you see the less elegant legacy persistent grey on white ones. Even if the scroll is not required! Probably Windows behaves similarly.

If I style the scrollbars with the `::-webkit-scrollbar` selectors, both the legacy and the overlay scrollbars gets overridden, resulting in always visible, although styled, scrollbars.

Is it possible to style only the legacy ones? And leave the beautiful overlays scrollbar when a mouse is not plugged? Thanks!

**Update**

Using [this technique](http://jsfiddle.net/eR9SP/444/) plus `overflow: auto` I arrived at a pretty good compromise.

Comment: in Chrome on Windows, the scrollbars don't display when there is nothing to scroll to if you set `overflow: auto`

Comment: There are other browsers don't have any scrollbar styling for example Firefox

Comment: @YvonneAburrow true, `overflow:auto` fixes the persistency